# Node.Js get data from a POST request

Tags: node.js, swift, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Im using Firebase cloud functions. On an iOS device, im deploying a trigger to run a cloud function in Node.Js. In Xcode - here is my client function to trigger the Cloud function - I'm passing over the dictionary **data**

```
func updateTermsOfServiceCloudCall(){

    let data = [
        "accountId": "acct_1Ew#######"
    ]

    Functions.functions().httpsCallable("updateAccountWithTOA").call(data) { (result, error) in
 }
```

Now in Node, i'm running this code to deploy to the Firebase cloud

```
exports.updateAccountWithTOA = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {


const data = request.body;
const accoundId = data.accoundId;

stripe.accounts.update(

    accoundId,
    {
        tos_acceptance: {
          date: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),
          ip: request.ip 
        }
      },
    )

});
```

I'm expecting to get the dictionary **data** that i passed over from my iOS client. However, im having an issue getting that data in Node. I thought **request.body** would give me the data, but i guess im wrong because i an getting this error. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

> Error: Stripe: Argument "id" must be a string, but got: undefined (on
>   API request to `POST /accounts/{id}`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your client code is trying to invoke a [callable function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), but your function is defined as an [HTTP type function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).  They are different things.  You can't invoke a regular HTTP function using the Functions SDK.

If you want to use the Functions SDK to invoke a function, it needs to be defined with onCall rather than onRequest, as shown in the [documentation for callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable).  Or, if you don't want a callable on the backend, you will need to invoke the regular HTTP function with an HTTP client library.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. So just to state -I used onCall for the other functions and successfully passed data through, so i understand you're correct on that.. However - for this specific cloud function, for some reason i can only get the "ip: ip.request" to work and write to Stripe is by calling that onRequest.. So, now I'm running into the issue where i can't pass the clients account id from the client to the server anymore.. If that makes sense ?

Comment: If you have a different problem than the one you first posted about, please post a new question and explain what's now not working the way you expect.